# ASP.NET MVC skeleton project, CSS question on the menu w.r.t. text-align

Tags: css

I create a new MVC project and there is a default Site.css file.
The default style creates a menu at the top, aligned to the right.

I look at the stylesheet, and I see on ul#menu, the text-align is set to right.  So I'm thinking setting it to left will make it go all the way to the left.

But it doesn't.  It ends up sitting somewhere in the middle.
What am I missing?

The relevant html is:

```
<body>
    <div class="page">

        <div id="header">
            <div id="title">
                <h1>My MVC Application</h1>
            </div>

            <div id="logindisplay">
                <% Html.RenderPartial("LogOnUserControl"); %>
            </div> 

            <div id="menucontainer">

                <ul id="menu">              
                    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("Home", "Index", "Home")%></li>
                    <li><%= Html.ActionLink("About", "About", "Home")%></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>

        <div id="main">
            <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="MainContent" runat="server" />

            <div id="footer">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

And the CSS:

```
ul#menu
{
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}

ul#menu li
{
    display: inline;
    list-style: none;
}

ul#menu li#greeting
{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    color: #fff;
}

ul#menu li a
{
    padding: 10px 20px;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-decoration: none;
    line-height: 2.8em;
    background-color: #e8eef4;
    color: #034af3;
}

ul#menu li a:hover
{
    background-color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li a:active
{
    background-color: #a6e2a6;
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul#menu li.selected a
{
    background-color: #fff;
    color: #000;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Text-align justifies text within a block element.  You need to float the elements.

First, float the menu by changing the ul#menu selector to this:

```
ul#menu
{
    border-bottom: 1px #5C87B2 solid;
    clear: both;
    float: left;
    padding: 0 0 2px;
    position: relative;
    margin: 0;
    text-align: right;
}
```

And than add this selector to clear the float:

```
#menucontainer:after
{
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response.  The style for "title" was floated left but there was no clear afterwards.  Of course you wouldn't have known that since that wasn't in the code sample.  But you did add clear: both in ul#menu which works too!

Comment: I don't want to float the menu left though, that makes my main sit next to it rather than below it.  I guess I could add another clear for main as well

Comment: I don't know what other css you've added, but the solution I gave you works.  I tried it with a new MVC site myself.  The menu is moved to the left and all other elements stayed where they were.